# Create Folder programatically in iPhone files APP

Tags: ios, swift

**Code:**

```
 let folderName = "coinFolder"
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
    let documentsFolder = try! fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let folderURL = documentsFolder.appendingPathComponent(folderName)
    let folderExists = (try? folderURL.checkResourceIsReachable()) ?? false
    do {
        if !folderExists {
            try! fileManager.createDirectory(at: folderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: false)
        }
        let destinationFileUrl = folderURL.appendingPathComponent("test23.pdf")
       // let hello = Data("hello".utf8)
       // try hello.write(to: fileURL)



        let urlString = ""
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        let fileName = String((url!.lastPathComponent)) as NSString
        // Create destination URL
        /* let documentsUrl:URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!
         let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName)")*/
        //Create URL to the source file you want to download
        let fileURL = URL(string: urlString)
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
        let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)
        let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in
            if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
                // Success
                if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                    print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
                }
                do {
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
                    do {
                        //Show UIActivityViewController to save the downloaded file
                        let contents  = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsFolder, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
                        for indexx in 0..<contents.count {
                            if contents[indexx].lastPathComponent == destinationFileUrl.lastPathComponent {
                                let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [contents[indexx]], applicationActivities: nil)
                                self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (let err) {
                        print("error: \(err)")
                    }
                } catch (let writeError) {
                    print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
                }
            } else {
                print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

i am working on sample a project to download PDF file and  create folder inside files app and store pdf file inside it.above code is what tried to achieve same.but it is not working for me.is it possible do so?if so what is wrong with my code. any help will be appricated.thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to change from `create:false` to `create:true`

Change from

```
let documentsFolder = try! fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
```

To

```
let documentsFolder = try! fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
```